# Serial communication PC x PIC

Tags: c++, vb.net, pic

I'm trying to communicate between my PC and a PIC16f873a, using vb.net on the PC and C++ in the PIC. I'm using a max232. I'm not able to light a light by pressing a button on PC:
EDIT:

```
Public Class Form1

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Close()
End Sub

Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Try
        SerialPort1.Open()
        Button7.Enabled = True
        Button6.Enabled = False
        GroupBox1.Enabled = True
        GroupBox2.Enabled = True
        GroupBox4.Enabled = True
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Connect to COM3"

    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message)
        MsgBox("COM. Port Not Found", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub Button7_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button7.Click
    SerialPort1.Close()
    Button7.Enabled = False
    Button6.Enabled = True
    GroupBox1.Enabled = False
    GroupBox2.Enabled = False
    GroupBox4.Enabled = False
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "No Connection"
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    SerialPort1.Write(CStr(Int(1)))
End Sub

Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    SerialPort1.Write(Chr(2))
End Sub

Private Sub Button8_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button8.Click
    SerialPort1.Write(Chr(CInt(TextBox1.Text)))
End Sub
End Class
```

And my PIC is:

```
#define LED1 PORTB.f0
unsigned char input;
void main() {
    TRISB = 0x00;
    PORTB = 0b00001110;
    SPBRG=129;
    TXSTA=0b00100110;
    RCSTA=0b10010000;
    UART1_Init(9600);           // initialize USART module
    delay_ms(100);              //  (8 bit, 9600 baud rate, no parity bit...)
    while (1) {
        PORTB.F1 = 1;
        if (Uart1_Data_Ready()) {
            input=uart1_read();
            if (input == 1)
                LED1 = 1;
            else
                LED1 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using a 20MHz xtal.

Comment: Are you sure the `SerialPort1` object is connecting to the right port with the right settings?  You didn't show that.  Are you able to make it work from a PC using a terminal app?

Comment: ups, sorry, i'm pretty sure it is connecting to the right port. I did it with COM3 to connect the max 232 and if it's not connected, a error message appears.

Comment: Are you sending the character '1' or the value 1? The PIC codes expects a single character with ASCII value 1, try changing the PIC code to `if (input == '1')` instead.

Comment: You need to initialize your SerialPort settings to match the one in PIC (9600 baud, etc.) Could you show us the schematic?